# How to load script from hive in display templates

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, display-template, script

I'm trying to load a script from the hive in my display template.

I've tried

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/1033/comany/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and

```
<script> 
    $includeScript(this.url, "/_layouts/15/1033/comany/js/bootstrap.min.js"); 
</script>
```

without any luck.

I've checked my network tab and it seems that you don't get the url where you are standing.

404 file not found   http:// _layouts /15/1033/styles/conpany/js/bootstrap.min.js
as you can see on the url it does not include the domain of the page.

The easy way would be to hard code the entire url, but I have several environments, so that would not be a good way to do this.

Comment: Try <SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="jqueryScriptLink" Localizable="false" runat="server" Name="/_layouts/CustomScripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></SharePoint:ScriptLink>

Comment: Does this work inside a display template?

Comment: You can try otherwise try SP.SOD.registerSod('jquery-1.7.1.min.js', this.L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/Preview Images/jquery-1.7.1.min.js");

Comment: Try loading it as:
$includeScript(this.url, "~sitecollection/_layouts/15/1033/comany/js/bootstrap.min.js");

_layouts is a virtual directly, so it can be referenced from any site collection.